# Running a Python script on CSV uploaded via HTML

Tags: php, python, html, scripting

I am trying to automatically run a python script using HTML and display the output of the python file in the website. This is part of my HTML code to run the python script:

```
<p>
    <?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:\xampp\htdocs\login\test.py');
    $output = system($command);
    echo $output;
    ?>
</p>
```

However, when I run this code, it opens up an instance of pycharm and runs the file. Instead, I want it to run the python file without opening up pycharm and display the output of the python file.

This is my python code:

```
def do_calculation(number1, number2):
    return number1 + number2

number1 = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
number2 = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
solution = do_calculation(number1, number2)
print("The sum of your numbers is {}".format(solution))
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but ultimately, I want to run a script that I wrote that analyzes a csv file the user uploaded onto the website and return some stats about the file such as number of missing values or number of repeated rows.

Comment: You should specific python path in your command.

Answer (score 0):

You've to specific the python path in your code.

1. `python --help` get the python path like, `D:\Programs\Anaconda3\python.exe`
2. change you `escapeshellcmd('C:\xampp\htdocs\login\test.py');` to `escapeshellcmd('D:/Programs/Anaconda3python.exe C:/xampphtdocslogintest.py');`

Comment: If you're in linux system, just add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the first line of your python script file.